# Can a function read the binding of another function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm currently learning javascript and I would appreciate some help.

I've been playing around trying to create a program that would multiply two numbers without using the * operator. I already found an easier way to do it than my approach but I'd like to know why the code I wrote doesn't work:

```
function addToItself(a) {
  a = a + a;
  return a;
}

function times(b) {
  for (count = 0; count < b; count++) {
    addToItself(a)
  }
  return a;
}

function multiply (x, y) {
  a = x;
  times(y);
}

let output = multiply(5, 2);
alert(output);
```

Is it not working because the binding "a" in the addToItself function has a local scope and the multiply function can't read it or is it something else?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There are multiple fundamental issues in your code. Variable scope and function return are two critical points you should research more. Learning some basic debugging techniques such as `console.log()` will also help your code writing improve. Learning how to debug is just as important  as learning how to write the actual code

Comment: I'll do some research on that. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the scope of each variable. In JavaScript, a variable declated within a function is scoped to that function. This means that a variable declared within a function can only be accessed within the function. Scopes are nested, so a variable declared globally is accessible inside a function too, though that's often discouraged.

Additionally, function arguments (such as `a` in `addToItself` and `b` in `times`) are treated like variables scoped to the function.

I would advise looking at the [MDN docs for "scope"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) and familiarizing yourself with how variables are scoped in JavaScript.

---

I have included a fixed version of your code is below, for reference:

```js
function addToItself(a) {
  // I used a new variable here since reassigning to an argument is discouraged
  const twoA = a + a;
  return twoA;
}
console.log('5 + 5 = ' + addToItself(5));

function times(value, times) {
  let temp = 0;
  
  for (let count = 0; count < times; count++) {
    temp += value;
  }
  
  return temp;
};
console.log('5 * 5 = ' + times(5, 5));
```

Comment: Neither the `var` nor the `let` keyword are used, so `a` is not scoped to the `multiply` function, it is a global variable. See the code snippet in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66090184/15023400). Otherwise, I agree with you.

Comment: Yes, but using a global variable like that isn't a good coding process. The fuctions are then tied to the containing scope, rather then being issolated and reusable.

Comment: Maybe you could explain that in your answer. I only wrote my comment, because `This means that the variable can only be accessed within the function.` is not true. Yes, using a global variable like this is not good practice. I think that not using the `var` or `let` keywords could lead to errors as the variables are bound to the global scope.

Comment: Yes, good point that the variables could actually be read from outside fo the functions scope. I will update my coment to add that.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! I'll check out the MDN docs link. Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: No problem Diego. If this answers your question, remember to mark it as the selected answer. It'll help other folks who have the same question find the answer (and me too!).

Answer (score -1):

No you can't read variable inside another function, there are easier way, like

```js
function multiply(x, y) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var count = 0; count < y; count++) {
    result += x
  }
  return result;
}

console.log("5 * 2 = " + multiply(5, 2));
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that the other answers dont already?

Comment: from the question, `I already found an easier ` he think the code is easier but not.